# How to merge array into single?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, merge

I am trying to transpose this array into single one. 
My input:

```
a = [[ array([  3.00514850e+05,   3.32400000e+01,   2.71669002e-01,
         6.50974961e+05,   3.00515112e+05,   3.32248995e+01])
  array([ 15.])]
 [ array([  3.00915200e+05,   2.90600000e+01,   2.91730634e-01,
         6.50763121e+05,   3.00915412e+05,   2.91246275e+01])
  array([ 17.])]
```

What i am trying to achieve:

```
 b = [[  3.00514850e+05,   3.32400000e+01,   2.71669002e-01,
         6.50974961e+05,   3.00515112e+05,   3.32248995e+01, 15.]
       [  3.00915200e+05,   2.90600000e+01,   2.91730634e-01,
         6.50763121e+05,   3.00915412e+05,   2.91246275e+01, 17.]]
```

So my plan is to first transpose my array into single one, split two arrays into individual and then append it together. I really feel like I over-complicating something.

I used **b = a.transpose()** to put all the values from small array to the end. After that i am trying to use **c, d = ([i] for i in b)** to split this to arrays and then my plan is to use **output = np.append(c, d)**.

But my function c, d trowing error  *"too many values to unpack (expected 2)"*.

Is there any better way to do it? What am I doing wrong? Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are trying to concatenate the arrays in all the sublist of your list `a`. You can do that using the built-in function `map`:

```
a = [[np.array([3.00514850e+05, 3.32400000e+01, 2.71669002e-01,
                6.50974961e+05, 3.00515112e+05, 3.32248995e+01]), np.array([15.])],
     [np.array([3.00915200e+05, 2.90600000e+01, 2.91730634e-01,
                6.50763121e+05, 3.00915412e+05, 2.91246275e+01]), np.array([17.])]]
a = np.array(a)
result = np.array(list(map(np.concatenate,a)))
```

Comment: Perfect! That's the answer what i was looking for!